# Purpose of negative CGSize values

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cgsize

Been reading the docs and found out that `CGSize` can take in negative values since it's more of a "vector" representation.

What's the purpose of this? Not saying that vectors can't be negatives, but what could the real world examples be that one would come across `CGSize` having negative `width` or `height`?

Note: Especially when there is already another data structure called `CGVector`

Comment: My only thought is coordinates. This is a poor example, but where `UIKit` uses the top-left as origin 0,0 - CoreImage uses the bottom-left. Computing (or describing) how to "flip-flop" between these two could use a negative value. Maybe?

Comment: One use of negative `CGSize` values is with [`CALayer.shadowOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410970-shadowoffset), which uses `CGSize` to describe an offset for some reason (instead of something that, in my opinion, would make more sense like `CGPoint` or `CGVector`).